# Remove some Child Items from Menu Control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, menu, submenu

I know this is a very common question asked. However, I have looked all over and couldn't find a good answer that will work for my scenario.
I have a MainMenu which has SubMenus. I need to remove some items from Submenus not all.
I can easily remove items from MainMenu by using 
`MainMenu.Items.Remove(e.Item)` in Databound event of the Menu

ForExample in following menu how can I remove sub2 from Main2 Menu.
Main1-
Main2->sub1,sub2

My Menu is bound to SiteMap.
I have tried `e.Item.ChildItems.RemoveAt(0)`, but `e.Item.ChildItems.Count` for Main2 is 0.
I don't know how to solve this.
Please help.

Comment: During which event you are trying to remove it? I'd guess you're doing it before the binding even happened, so it returns you an empty collection...

Comment: This article may help: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/06/24/managing-menus-1.aspx

Comment: Wow ... that article answered the question I had exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If your menu is bound to SiteMap and you want to remove items, don't you need to make a new map and bind to that?